# Guzzle6 Client and CLientInterface file Namespaces not resolving in custom PHP Class

Tags: php, guzzle6

I have a php class that is using Client from Guzzle 6 and composer but when I try to load my page I get an error saying: `PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface' not found` even though I am importing the correct class. When I ctrl click the use statement it takes me directly to the ClientInterface.php in Guzzle. I am unsure why I am getting the PHP error. Any ideas? I tried importing and including, neither works.

Method 1:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
```

Method 2:

```
require_once 'vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php';
require_once 'vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/ClientInterface.php';
```